# Stored procedure unsure syntax

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will determine if my customerid exists if it exists then my other parameter foundcustomer will be assigned to found otherwise not found. I am unsure how to assign found please help
here is what i tried

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE procedure4
   -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FoundCustomer varchar(10) = null,
    @Customerid varchar (5) = null
   AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here

if Not(@Customerid is null)

SELECT customerid
  from customers
  where customerid = @Customerid
```

END
GO

Comment: What RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: What do you want the stored procedure to return?  Perhaps you really want a function, not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon is right, it sounds like you may want a function but if it has to be a stored procedure you can follow this example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure4 
    @Customerid varchar(5) = null
AS 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FoundCustomer varchar(10) = ''

    IF @FoundCustomer is not null

    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM customers WHERE customerid = @customerid) > 0
            SET @FoundCustomer = 'Found'
        ELSE 
            SET @FoundCustomer = 'Not Found'
    END

    SELECT @FoundCustomer

END
```